# Unexpected behaviour using group in Crossfilterjs

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, crossfilter

I have a Crossfilterjs dimension on a key corresponding to an object.

I group on one of the attributes of the object and use reduceCount() to find counts of values for that attribute, but the results are not what I expected.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.9/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script>
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < 100; k++) arr.push({a: i, e: { b: j, c: k}});
    }
}

var cf = crossfilter(arr),
    a  = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.a; }),
    e  = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.e; });

var counts = e.group(function(d) { return d.b; })
              .reduceCount()
              .orderNatural()
              .top(Infinity);

console.log(counts);

</script>
```

When I check the console I get an array with 67 key/value objects.

I was expecting to get an array with 100 key/value objects, one for each value of b.

Also some of the counts aren't what I expected. I expected all of the values to be the same. However, for most keys I get a value of 100 and for a few I get very different values. The key 99 has a value of 990100.

I got these results in Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m.

I haven't used custom grouping functions before in Crossfilterjs and it seems like I don't understand the functionality properly.

I looked up grouping on the Crossfilterjs API, but it didn't help me clear things up.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mea culpa

When I read over the docs I didn't notice this:

> groupValue must return a naturally-ordered value;
>   furthermore, this order must be consistent with the dimension's value function

My grouping value is a string, which has a natural ordering but my dimension is created on an object which doesn't. The inconsistency between the orderings must be causing the problem.

Then I noticed another section in the docs which addresses the problem of ordering on my dimension:

> crossfilter.dimension() constructs a new dimension using the specified value accessor 
>   function. The function must return naturally-ordered values, i.e., values that behave
>   correctly with respect to JavaScript's <, <=, >= and > operators. This typically means primitives: booleans, numbers or strings; however, you can override object.valueOf to provide a comparable value from a given object, such as a Date.

Comment: Yup, I'm pretty sure this is the problem. Creating a dimension on an object probably isn't going to end well.

Comment: This is the problem. I followed the docs advice of overriding the valueOf method for my object and everything seems to be working fine now. Too early to accept my own answer though. Thanks for commenting nonetheless.